# What is the meaning of "spam = spam + 1"

Tags: python, while-loop

I'm new to the python programming language and I have a question.

```
spam = 0
while spam < 5:
    print('Hello, world.')
spam = spam + 1
```

What is the meaning of the last line? I searched but unfortunately, I wasn't able to find the very answer to my question. Thank you beforehand!

Comment: The indentation is wrong. This is an infinite loop and you won't reach the last line.

Comment: 1) Your indentation is most likely wrong. 2) Next time, before you ask a question, print out the value before and after the command to see what the command does with the variable. If it is still unclear, go to a tutorial site. Or run it in [PythonTutor](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) which helps you understand simple scripts.  If then still questions remain, ask it on SO.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it doesn't show any research or effort. According to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274645/how-to-deal-with-questions-that-ask-about-complete-basics basic questions should be closed and/or downvoted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted, `spam = spam + 1` increases the value of `spam` by one.

That makes more sense if the program you are looking at is actually this:

```
spam = 0
while spam < 5:
    print('Hello, world.')
    spam = spam + 1
```

Now the `spam = spam + 1` is part of the loop body ... and whole program is going to print "Hello, world" 5 times.

Indentation is **significant** to the meaning of a program in Python.

Answer (score 0):

`spam = spam + 1` means to `add` `1` to the `previous` value of `spam` and `assign` the new value to `spam` variable again.

If we elaborate `spam = spam + 1` is equavelent to

```py
spam = 0
temporary_variable = spam + 1 # temporary_variable = 0 + 1 = 1
spam = temporary_variable # spam = 1
```

For example:

```py
spam = 2020
spam = spam + 1
print(spam) # spam will be 2021 since 2020 + 1 = 2021
```